# Unable to find DOM element using Enzyme find()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a memory game where I want to test if clicking a turned memory card displays the image but I am unable to get a reference to the element using Enzyme. Let me outline the use case:

[image]

user is presented with memory cards images displayed;

[image]

user clicked the blue button below. All cards are 'turned' and onClickhandler is active.

At this point, when a card is clicked, it is flipped and the image is visible. I want to write a test doing just that, and test if 2 identical cards are counted etc. But I am not able to reference any props on the selected card.

This is my test:

```
   describe("Test the puzzle", () => {
const component = mount(<Board />);
it("should show 1 turned card when clicked", () => {
    const button = component.find(".button");
    const card = component.find(".card");
    const turnedCards = [];

    expect(button).toBeDefined();
    expect(card).toBeDefined();
    act(() => {
        button.props().onClick({});
    });
    card.props().onClick({});
});
```

});

The test fails with message

```
 ● Test the puzzle › should show 1 turned card when clicked

Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

  34 |                      button.props().onClick({});
  35 |              });
> 36 |              card.props().onClick({});                         :13)
     |                   ^                                            7)
  37 |      });
  38 | });                                                            t.js:21856:12)
  39 |                                                                js:929:14)

  at ReactWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:1168:13)
```

"0 found instead." means there is no DOM element selected here even though the developer tools show a div.class element (actually 36 in this board).

[image]

This is strange because I was able to select the button (`const button = component.find(".button");`) and do

```
button.props().onClick({});
```

What am I missing here?

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
```

Comment: can you include the `Board` component?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mDubABw9

Comment: `const button = component.find('button').simulate('click');`

Comment: Should maybe add that the element I want to access is a React _functional_ component, if that makes any difference?

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference. Did you try the simulate click option that i gave?

Comment: the button is not the problem, the div.card cannot be found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224255/discussion-between-marc-and-uks).